# Evaluating Line Integrals!

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics

$3xy^2dx+2x^3dy$ 
where  is the boundary of the region between the circles $x^2+y^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=64$ having positive orientation.

Not quite sure how to evaluate this...

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to know ... could you reformulate your question please ? If by evaluating the integral you mean: $X=\displaystyle\int_{x\in I}3xy^2dx+\int_{y\in J}2x^3dy$  then what are $I$ and $J$ ? Maybe you meant that $x$ and $y$ are bound by the two circle equations ? Anyways, you see there are lots of interpretations of your question so try and make it a bit clearer ;)

Comment: Oh ok, I guess you want to evaluate the area of the region between your two circles by calculating the line integrals. Is that it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so let's assume what I asked in my comment is actually what you're looking for.

So the first step is to write your circle equations in parametric form:

**First circle $C_1$:** $x^2+y^2=25=5^2$

This means you have: $\cases{x=5\cos(t) \\ y=5\sin(t)}$

And: $\cases{dx=-5\sin(t)dt \\ dy=5\cos(t)dt}$

**Second circle $C_2$:** $x^2+y^2=64=8^2$

This means you have: $\cases{x=8\cos(t) \\ y=8\sin(t)}$

And: $\cases{dx=-8\sin(t)dt \\ dy=8\cos(t)dt}$

The area $A$ of the region between the two circles is equal to $A=A_2-A_1$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are respectively the areas of circles $C_1$ and $C_2$.

And you know that: $\displaystyle\cases{A_1=\frac{1}{2}\int_{C_1}xdy-ydx \\ A_2=\frac{1}{2}\int_{C_2}xdy-ydx}$

Now replace in both those equations the parametric forms of $x$,$y$,$dx$ and $dy$ and you'll be good to go (you'll see it simplifies a lot) ;)

Oh and don't forget, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ for your integrals !

Comment: Well the question wasn't very clear so I assumed since he was talking about line integrals that he wanted to evaluate an area. And since he was talking about the region between two circles, this is why I answered this way ;)

Comment: where did you get the equations for c1 and c2... Why didn't you use the f(x,y) equation?

Answer (score 2):

One way of evaluating integral $\int\limits_{\partial{D}}{3xy^2 \, dx+2x^3\,dy}$ along the boundary  $\partial{D}$ of the domain $D=\{(x,\;y)\colon \;\;\; 25< x^2+y^2<64 \},$ which is an annulus between two circles $C_1=\{(x,\;y)\colon \;\;\;  x^2+y^2= 64 \}$ and $C_2=\{(x,\;y)\colon \;\;\;  x^2+y^2= 25 \},$ is parametrization, proposed by   @Dolma.
 These parametrizations are 
$$C_1 =\{(8\cos{t},\;8\sin{t}), \;\; {0}\leqslant{t}\leqslant{2\pi} \} \\
C_2 =\{(5\cos{t},\;5\sin{t}), \;\; {0}\leqslant{t}\leqslant{2\pi} \}.
$$
Then 
$$\int\limits_{\partial{D^{+}}}{3xy^2 \, dx+2x^3\,dy}=\int\limits_{{C_1^+}\cup{C_2^-}}{3xy^2 \, dx+2x^3\,dy}= \\
=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\left(3(8\cos{t})(8\sin{t})^2(-8\sin{t}) +2(8\cos{t})^3(8 \cos{t}) \right)\,dt} -\\
-\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\left(3(5 \cos{t})(5 \sin{t})^2(-5\sin{t}) +2(5\cos{t})^3(5 \cos{t}) \right)\,dt} .$$
Another way  uses the [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)
$$\int\limits_{\partial{D^{+}}}{3x^2 \, dx+2x^3\,dy}=\iint\limits_{D}{\left(\dfrac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}(2x^3)-\dfrac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}}(3xy^2)\right)}\,dx\,dy= \iint\limits_{D}{\left(6x^2-6xy\right)}\,dx\,dy.$$
Last integral can be evaluated by using polar coordinates 
$$\begin{cases}x=\rho\cos{\theta} \\
 y=\rho\sin{\theta} \end{cases}$$
$$
\iint\limits_{D}{\left(6x^2-6xy\right)}\,dx\,dy=6\int\limits_{5}^{8}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\rho^2 \left(\cos^2{\theta}-\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\right)}\rho\,d{\theta}\,d{\rho}=\\
=6\int\limits_{5}^{8}{\rho^3 \,d{\rho} }\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{}\left(\cos^2{\theta}-\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\right)\,d{\theta}
$$